# Dynamically populate object values with function calls

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working with a VueJS app that incorporates the following helper class and method:

```
class BiometricMap {
  static get(bioType) {
    if (!bioType) {
      return BiometricMap.default();
    }

    const bioTypes = {
      40: () => this.getFace(),
      41: () => this.getFace(),
      42: () => this.getFace(),
      43: () => this.getFace(),
      60: () => this.getVoice(),
      61: () => this.getVoice(),
      140: () => this.getPin(),
      141: () => this.getPin(),
      150: () => this.getPalm(),
      152: () => this.getPalm(),
    };

    return (bioTypes[bioType])();
  }

  static getFace() {
    return {
      friendly: 'Face',
      type: 'face',
      icon: 'face',
    };
  }

  static getPalm() {
    return {
      friendly: 'Palm',
      type: 'palm',
      icon: 'pan_tool',
    };
  }

  static getPin() {
    return {
      friendly: 'PIN',
      type: 'pin',
      icon: 'radio_button_checked',
    };
  }

  static getVoice() {
    return {
      friendly: 'Voice',
      type: 'voice',
      icon: 'keyboard_voice',
    };
  }

  static default() {
    return {
      friendly: '',
      type: '',
      icon: '',
    };
  }
}

export default BiometricMap;
```

I need to convert it to be dynamic, since the list of `bioTypes` values can change, so I modified `get()` like so:

```
import BiometricService from '../services/BiometricService';
...

  static async get(bioType) {
    if (!bioType) {
      return BiometricMap.default();
    }

    const bioTypes = {};
    const baseBioTypes = await BiometricService.fetchAll();

    baseBioTypes.data.forEach((type) => {
      // Yet another place we have to convert 'passphrase' to 'voice'.
      const captureType = type.captureType === 'passphrase' ? 'voice' : type.captureType;
      const methodName = `get${captureType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + captureType.slice(1)}()`;
      bioTypes[type.bioType] = () => this[methodName];
    });

    return (bioTypes[bioType])();
  }
```

This seems to work, in that I correctly generate the `methodName` value and add it to the `bioTypes` object. However, when it gets to

```
return (bioTypes[bioType])();
```

it doesn't call the appropriate method (e.g. `getFace()`, `getVoice()`, etc.). What do I need to change in how I'm populating the `bioTypes` object so that the appropriate method is called?

Comment: The line with 'bioTypes[type.bioType] = () => this[methodName];' just assigns function, which returns your function, instead of calling it directly. So either call it instead of returning, or change your ' return (bioTypes[bioType])();' to ' return (bioTypes[bioType])()();'

Comment: Using `return (bioTypes[bioType])()();` gives me an `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: bioTypes[bioType](...) is not a function` error. In regards to your first suggestion, at that point I'm just creating the object so I can call the appropriate method based on the `bioType` value later, so I wouldn't want to call it there.

Answer (score 0):

This line seems potentially wrong:

```js
const methodName = `get${captureType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + captureType.slice(1)}()`;
```

So if `captureType` is `voice` then `methodName` will be `getVoice()`. I don't think you want the `()` on the end.

Then there's this:

```js
bioTypes[type.bioType] = () => this[methodName];
```

It becomes clearer what the problem is if we write it out in full:

```js
bioTypes[type.bioType] = function () {
  // Ignoring the scoping issue for a moment...
  return this[methodName];
}
```

The function is returning your method rather than invoking it.

Instead you want:

```js
bioTypes[type.bioType] = () => this[methodName]();
```

Here's a complete example with those mistakes corrected:

```js
BiometricService = {
  async fetchAll () {
    return {
      data: [
        { bioType: 40, captureType: 'face' },
        { bioType: 41, captureType: 'face' },
        { bioType: 42, captureType: 'face' },
        { bioType: 43, captureType: 'face' },
        { bioType: 60, captureType: 'passphrase' },
        { bioType: 61, captureType: 'passphrase' },
        { bioType: 140, captureType: 'pin' },
        { bioType: 141, captureType: 'pin' },
        { bioType: 150, captureType: 'palm' },
        { bioType: 152, captureType: 'palm' }
      ]
    };
  }
};

class BiometricMap {
  static async get(bioType) {
    if (!bioType) {
      return BiometricMap.default();
    }

    const bioTypes = {};
    const baseBioTypes = await BiometricService.fetchAll();

    baseBioTypes.data.forEach((type) => {
      // Yet another place we have to convert 'passphrase' to 'voice'.
      const captureType = type.captureType === 'passphrase' ? 'voice' : type.captureType;
      const methodName = `get${captureType.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${captureType.slice(1)}`;
      bioTypes[type.bioType] = () => this[methodName]();
    });

    return (bioTypes[bioType])();
  }

  static getFace() {
    return {
      friendly: 'Face',
      type: 'face',
      icon: 'face',
    };
  }

  static getPalm() {
    return {
      friendly: 'Palm',
      type: 'palm',
      icon: 'pan_tool',
    };
  }

  static getPin() {
    return {
      friendly: 'PIN',
      type: 'pin',
      icon: 'radio_button_checked',
    };
  }

  static getVoice() {
    return {
      friendly: 'Voice',
      type: 'voice',
      icon: 'keyboard_voice',
    };
  }

  static default () {
    return {
      friendly: '',
      type: '',
      icon: '',
    };
  }
}

(async () => {
  console.log('40 :', await BiometricMap.get(40));
  console.log('60 :', await BiometricMap.get(60));
  console.log('140 :', await BiometricMap.get(140));
  console.log('150 :', await BiometricMap.get(150));
})()
```

I would add that it seems a bit odd to load all the `bioTypes` every time, build up a data structure in `bioTypes` and then just invoke one of them, throwing all the others away. There seems to be a lot of work going on to achieve a single method call.

In its present form it could be reduced down to this:

```js
static async get(bioType) {
  if (!bioType) {
    return BiometricMap.default();
  }

  const baseBioTypes = await BiometricService.fetchAll();

  for (const type of baseBioTypes.data) {
    if (type.bioType === bioType) {
      const captureType = type.captureType === 'passphrase' ? 'voice' : type.captureType
      const methodName = `get${captureType.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${captureType.slice(1)}`
      return this[methodName]()
    }
  }

  // TODO: Handle fall-through
}
```

For the existing version to make sense there would need to be some way in which it retains the object `bioTypes` so that it gets used more than once. Even then I would be more inclined for it to contain just the mappings from the `bioType` to the  `methodName` string rather than creating all those wrapper functions.

Comment: Well, in the bigger picture, this is a file that is called from a Vuex module, and the data returned from `BiometricService.fetchAll();` is already available in state, but if I try to include my store file, I run into circular inclusion issues.

Comment: @wonder95 I have updated my answer to include a complete working demo of the changes I originally suggested, using the data from your implementation as mock data for `BiometricService.fetchAll`. It is effectively just the two changes I suggested, though I did also tweak the string interpolation. The rest should be the same as your version. I've also added a further paragraph to the end to expand on why I don't really understand the approach, even if it does work.

Comment: FYI `this[methodName].bind(this)` can be used instead of `() => this[methodName]()` (based on personal preference)

Comment: @skirtle Thanks, I am looking at this. As I mentioned in a previous comment, the data is available in Vuex state, so yes, ideally I would get it from there, but because this file is imported into a Vuex module file, if I try to include the `store.js` file, I get circular inclusion issues. I'm trying to figure how to get around it.